# cts search returning wrong results for wildcarded search

Tags: search, marklogic

Facing an issue with ‘wildcarded’ search for ‘unfiltered’ cts search query.

Problem explanation:
I have inserted the below docs in DB.

```
xdmp:document-insert('/a/a1.xml', <root><aa>123</aa></root>);
xdmp:document-insert('/a/a2.xml', <root><aa>12</aa></root>);
xdmp:document-insert('/a/a3.xml', <root><aa>1</aa></root>);
```

In the below query I am looking for documents having only one digit in ‘aa’ element.

But the below query returning me all the documents I have inserted above.

```
cts:search(
    doc(),
    cts:element-word-query(xs:QName('aa'), '?', ('wildcarded')),
    'unfiltered'
)
```

If I will perform ‘filtered’ search I am getting the right result which is doc ‘/a/a3.xml.

Same issue is when the search term is ‘??’(docs expected which contain two digit number in ‘aa’ element) and 
‘???’ (docs expected which contain three digit number in ‘aa’ element)

Below indexes are set to true:

- three character searches
- three character word positions
- fast element character searches
- trailing wildcard searches
- trailing wildcard word positions
- fast element trailing wildcard searches

I am curious to know why this is happening and how can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

An unfiltered search can only return accurate results if there is an index that can satisfy the query. You can see how your query is being formulated to index resolution using [`xdmp:plan`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:plan): 
`xdmp:plan(
  cts:search(doc(),cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("aa"),"?","wildcarded"))`

In your case, you have no index that can do this and the plan will show that you are just asking for all documents with that element in them. The three character and trailing wildcard indexes only work if there are three or more non-wildcard characters, and the fast element character index just means to apply whatever character indexes you have with the element context. We recommend that for wildcards you add a codepoint collation word lexicon. You can add it to the database as a whole, or, if you know you only need these kinds of wildcards for this particular element, you can add an element word lexicon. Lexicon expansion can then be used to resolve the wildcard.

This happens in a heuristic way automatically (which is to say, depending on the size of your database and the number of lexicon matches, we may formulate the query in more or less accurate ways), but there are also various options to force the handling to behave a certain way. See the API for [cts:element-word-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-word-query?q=cts:element-word-query&v=9.0&api=true)

Comment: Regarding Mary's comment - in your example, I would definitely lean towards term-expansion by way of an element-word-lexicon. There are many times in which I would choose this rather then turning on 2 and 3 char wildcards as well.

Comment: One footnote on this good advice:  if you want all documents that contain an element, use cts:element-query(xs:QName('aa'), cts:and-query(())).  In MarkLogic 9, you can replace cts:and-query(()) with the more readable but equivalent cts:true-query().